# How to recode bands in which max value occur using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster

I have 2 raster images; ras1 (an image with max value) and ras2 (an image with 5 bands). Basically. ras1 image extracted from ras2 images.

I'd like to find bands from ras2 in which max value occur and recode them 1 to 5. For example, ras2 has band1, b2, b3, b4, b5. if max value of ras1 occur in band 3, 3 return to output, if max of ras1 occur in band 4, 4 return to output etc.

Could you give me suggestion what tool in Arcgis has ability to do this?

I used inlist tool, but it gave me the values (not the number 1-5).

Comment: You have described the [Highest Position](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Highest_Position/009z0000007v000000/) operation.

Comment: @whuber I wasn't aware of the Highest Position function when I posted my answer. I guess it's a more ArcGIS-y solution. It should be noted that it requires Spatial Analyst, whereas the numpy solution does not - this may or may not be an issue (we have to fight for an SA licence from the network pool at my workplace...)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the numpy.argmax() function. Enter the following into the Python console (adjust to taste):

```
import arcpy
import numpy

# convert the raster to a 3-dimensional numpy array (x, y, band)
values = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray("ras2")

# calculate the index of the maximum value along the band axis

#(1-based, rather than the default 0-based)
indices = numpy.argmax(values, axis=2) + 1

# write the output to a new raster
raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(indices)
raster.save('C:/ArcGIS/maximum.tif')
```

Not tested, as I don't have ArcGIS to hand...

Relevant documentation:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000012z000000